# How to open a new JFrame and focus on a specific tab of JTabbedPane placed in the new JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 `JFrame`s:

- first frame has a 3 `JButton`s: #1 #2 #3
- second frame has a `JTabbedPane` with 3 tabs, each with a `JPanel`

When I press one of the buttons from first frame I want to open the second frame and focus on the corresponding tab in `JTabbedPane` (button #1 -> tab #1, button #2 -> tab #2, etc)

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Modifica");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                FirmaDateModifica frame = new FirmaDateModifica();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                // Is there something I can do here?
            }
        });
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) first.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a public method in `FirmaDateModifica` that takes an integer parameter as the tab index and then changes that currently selected tab in that frame.  You should add an action listener to each of the three buttons and then use the different tab indexes as the parameters when calling the function that changes the tab in the second frame.